# Liquibase call procedure without database specification

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql, liquibase

Is the way to call stored procedure without database specification? For example:

1. `<changeSet author="name" id="id1" dbms="mysql">
       <sql>
           EXEC procedure_name('some_string_value')
       </sql>
   </changeSet>`
2. `<changeSet author="name" id="id2" dbms="oracle">
       <sql>
           EXECUTE procedure_name('some_string_value')
       </sql>
   </changeSet>`
3. `<changeSet author="name" id="id3" dbms="postgresql">
       <sql>
           SELECT fun_name('some_string_value')
       </sql>
   </changeSet>`

I need avoid database conditions because I call this procedure in different places. Is there a way to achieve this with implementing db condition in one place?

Comment: As far as I know, Liquibase has no abstraction layer for calling a stored procedure, using the `dbms` attribute is the only way to do this. Btw: you can use `perform` like that in Postgres outside of a PL/pgSQL block. You need to use `select fun_name(...)` (and it should be  `dbms="postgresql"` not `postgree`).

Comment: The main point for me on liquidbase level call procedure in one way. And changesets above just for explain question.

Comment: That doesn't change my answer: "*As far as I know, Liquibase has no abstraction layer for calling a stored procedure*"

Comment: Maybe there is some trick to achieve this =)

Comment: I deleted my answer after re-reading the question and realizing it does not actually answer what you're asking. I answered with instructions on how to define properties in a separate file that can be reused across different changesets, but it still uses the dbms attribute. I can undelete it if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I guess I find solution.

Comment: Rather than putting the answer in the question, it would be better (for future StackOverflow users) to answer your own question and select it as the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that user can answer own question. I'll change this in correct way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find solution:

```
<property name="call.procedure" value="EXEC" dbms="oracle" />
<property name="call.procedure" value="SELECT" dbms="postgresql" />
<property name="call.procedure" value="EXEC" dbms="mssql" />
<property name="before.param" value="(" dbms="oracle" />
<property name="before.param" value="(" dbms="postgresql" />
<property name="before.param" value=" @Name=" dbms="mssql" />
<property name="after.param" value=")" dbms="oracle" />
<property name="after.param" value=")" dbms="postgresql" />
<property name="after.param" value="" dbms="mssql" />
```

Now I can avoid specifying database name in changesets and call procedures in one line for different databases.

```
<changeSet author="andrew" id="id">
  <sql>
    ${call.procedure} cd_test ${before.param}'some_string'${after.param}   
  </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<sqlFile
  path=“xxx.sql”
  relativeToChangelogFile=“true”
  stripComments=“true”
  splitStatements=“false”
  endDelimiter=“/”
  dbms=“oracle”
/>
```

and .sql file should have

```
BEGIN
    package.function();
END;
/
```